# Excel formula return wrong result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working with excel2007, french version.

here is a very simplified version of my issue:

in a cell I use the formula: `=SI(5 > 0;"A";"B")` As 5 is bigger than 0 I expect the result `"A"`

When I open the function wizard, it is what I get

When I follow the formula evaluation I get:

```
SI(5 > 0;"A";"B")
SI(VRAI;"A";"B")
0
```

An the result in the cell is 0 ???

**[edit]** The excel process looked to be OK, it was possible to modify cells, use menu... but it didn't close when I asked it. I had to kill it. Then when I reopen the file (after a PC reboot), the formula works as expected. If I can reproduce this I will update the title and give precision about the scenario to get it.

Comment: Shot in the dark: do the spaces in your first argument make a difference?  Everything else looks fine.

Comment: ...And, even though you are using excel2007, french version, go to settings and make sure the locality settings are what you expect.

Comment: @ryyker - I just checked, it doesn't matter if you have spaces, Excel cuts them out.  Pascal, you've tried `=Si(5>0,"A","B")` and it doesn't work?  Perhaps try using commas instead of semicolons as a quick check.

Comment: @BruceWayne - yes, my excel clears spaces also, but I am not using _excel2007, french version_.  Are you?

Comment: @ryyker - ah, good point. I assumed all Excel versions would do that, but that's probably not a good assumption.

Comment: There have been enough problems with the french versions for Excel in particular that it has almost become a cliche.

Comment: In french version the space are kept, at least when I edit the formula. removing them has no effect, replacing semi colon by coma gives an error. replacing "A" and "B" by 1 and 2 has n effect. Precision I am editing VBA macros. leaving the macro edition ha no effect.

Comment: Well, it appears we are approaching a conclusion.  _Is it possible that this is an as of yet undiscovered bug with that formula_?.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but please double check the cell format and make sure it's set to General (or equivalent in the French Excel version).  Some cell formats can cause this issue.

Comment: Well I use it every times, and it works. I get in this issue after filling the sheet automatically by a VBA macro `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=if(RC[-3]=40,""A"",""B"")`

Comment: in `RC[-3]` is _-3_ a valid index?

Comment: I guess in the french version it is "format cellule/Standard". It has no effect.

Comment: Ooh, ok.  If the logic test is referencing a cell, make sure your workbook calculation is set to Automatic instead of Manual.

Comment: should `=if(RC` be `si(RC` ?  ***And in this VBA insert***, I notice you use comma delimiters, where it has been established that semi-colons should be used.

Comment: Yes the index is valid, in the original case, the formula is in J6

Comment: the if and the coma are modified by si and semicolon in excel. I guess it is a matter of presentation, but inside it is interpreted as `if(cond,true,false)`

Comment: @tigeravatar -  FWIW, I tried in my version (not french) to set the format to something other than General, several times, all worked fine.  This does not mean that it would not be a problem for the french version though.

Comment: @ryyker as an example, set the cell format to custom using `;;;"0"` and you will see the behavior described in the OP.  I do realize that something like that is very improbable though

Comment: I tried to quit excel, it is not possible, I tried to kill the application, the task manager is stuck. I think I will reboot the PC, I will update this post according to the results.

Comment: @Pascal  What is the actual value in `RC[-3]`?  If it is a formula, it may not be evaluating to exactly 40.